# CSS / JQuery Rotating Banners, Remember which was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been looking at this issue for the past could of days and I can't for the life of me work out the best way of doing it.

I have 5 circles (images) that have different text inside them. What I need to do is when one of the other 4 circles are clicked I need it to switch out with the one that was clicked and replace the text... the one clicked then needs to become the middle circle, etc.

Here is a codepen of what I have so far: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yKZyVQ

Could anyone help or point me in the right direction?

**HTML**

```
<div class="new-circle-wrapers">
  <div class="circles-arrow-left"></div>
  <div class="circles-arrow-right"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 mx-auto">

    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084428/c1_img2.png" class="img-fluid circle-images" data-size="small" data-img-large="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084427/c1_img4.png"
      data-img-medium="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084427/c1_img4.png" data-img-small="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084427/c1_img4.png" data-text="This is normally for the more experienced faster only. Water fasting has to be done carefully and
                    is not for everyone. A high degree of supervision is required for water fasting and our Doctor
                    and naturopathic health team will assess if this is suitable for you or not." />
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084428/c1_img2.png" class="img-fluid circle-images" data-size="medium" data-img-large="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084427/c1_img4.png"
      data-img-medium="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084427/c1_img4.png" data-img-small="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084427/c1_img4.png" data-text="For newbie fasters having a juice supplemented with some fruits, like apple and pears, which are
                    high in fructose, can be a very gentle start. Often people starting on this move to vegetable
                    juicing after a few days." />
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084428/c1_img2.png" class="img-fluid circle-images master-circle" data-size="large" data-img-large="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/230844278/c1_img4.png"
      data-img-medium="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084427/c1_img4.png" data-img-small="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084427/c1_img4.png" data-text="Drinking freshly made organic vegetable juices. This can just be green vegetables, such as cucumbers,
                    courgettes or spinach. Beetroot and carrots have a modicum of fructose (natural sugars). Although breaking
                    down these sugars adds a minimal load to the liver, these vegetables have high levels of beta-carotene
                    which offer exceptional health benefits to the mucus membranes in the eyes, lungs and gut." />
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084428/c1_img2.png" class="img-fluid circle-images" data-size="medium" data-img-large="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084427/c1_img4.png"
      data-img-medium="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084427/c1_img4.png" data-img-small="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084427/c1_img4.png" data-text="There is another option we commonly recommend, which is a mixture of juices, smoothies and soups.
                    It’s all liquid but does include some fibre. This simple addition can really support someone for
                    whom who we think the slight stress of fasting could be detrimental. Often this is appropriate
                    for clients who have fatigue, where we’re trying to detox them and nourish them at the same time." />
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084427/c1_img4.png" class="img-fluid circle-images" data-size="small" data-img-large="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084427/c1_img4.png"
      data-img-medium="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084427/c1_img4.png" data-img-small="https://s3.amazonaws.com/magoosh-company-site/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2012/08/23084427/c1_img4.png" data-text="Recently popularised by Dr Michael Mosley who introduced the 5:2 diet. Intermittent     fasting is
                    juicing or reducing calories for 2 days per week. This is often a better option for people with
                    particular medical conditions or/and for newbie fasters." />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 my-5 mx-auto text-center cirle-text">
    Drinking freshly made organic vegetable juices. This can just be green vegetables, such as cucumbers, courgettes or spinach. Beetroot and carrots have a modicum of fructose (natural sugars). Although breaking down these sugars adds a minimal load to the
    liver, these vegetables have high levels of beta-carotene which offer exceptional health benefits to the mucus membranes in the eyes, lungs and gut.
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
  width: 70px !important;
  height: 70px !important;
}

.slick-next {
  right: -75px !important;
}

.circle-images {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.circle-images:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.new-circle-wrapers {
  display: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.circle-text-hidden {
  display: none;
}

/*.circles-arrow-left, .circles-arrow-right {
  display: none;
}*/

/* Small phones portrait */
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .circle-images:nth-child(1), .circle-images:nth-child(2), .circle-images:nth-child(4), .circle-images:nth-child(5) {
    display: none;
  }

  .circles-arrow-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 90px;
    border-left: 40px solid #636363;
  }

  .circles-arrow-left {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    border-right:40px solid #636363;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 90px;
  }

}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".circle-images").on("click", function() {
    var currentText = $(".cirle-text").html();
    var currentImage = $(".master-circle").attr("src");

    $(".cirle-text").html($(this).data("text"));
    $(".master-circle").attr("src", $(this).data("img-large"));

    $(this).data("text", currentText);
    $(this).data("img-large", currentImage);
  });
});
```

Comment: Are the 4 non-selected circles/images all going to be identical in your end state? Or is that just for illustration?

Comment: Thats just for illustration @Stevangelista... the final images have text inside them with the title of the issue.